# How do I list occurrences of certian values found in a dictionary in a list in python?

Tags: python

```
dave = [{'date':'12/10/12','time':'09:12','created_by':'adam','text':'this'},
        {'date':'28/09/11','time':'15:58','created_by':'admin','text':'that'},
        {'date':'03/01/10','time':'12:34','created_by':'admin','text':'this and that'}]
```

How to I get a list of the values found in `created_by`. (e.g. `['adam','admin']`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` factory to return only unique value, and then you can get back the `list` using `list` factory over your `set`: -

```
>>> set(x['created_by'] for x in dave)
set(['admin', 'adam'])

>>> list(set(x['created_by'] for x in dave))
['admin', 'adam']
```

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension will work nicely:

```
[ x['created_by'] for x in dave if 'created_by' in x ]
```

If you're absolutely sure that `'created_by'` is a key in each dict contained in `dave`, you can leave off the `if 'created_by' in x` part -- it would raise a `KeyError` if that key is missing in that case.

Of course, if you want *unique* values, then you need to decide if order is important.  If order isn't important, a `set` is the way to go:

```
set(x['created_by'] for x in dave if 'created_by' in x)
```

If order is important, refer to [this classic question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/748858)

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a set, then back to a list...

```
list(set(d['created_by'] for d in dave))
```

Answer (score 0):

An advancement of the list comprehension is to use the if conditional for items that may not have a 'created_by'. When working with messy data this is often required.

```
list(set(x['created_by'] for x in dave if 'created_by' in x))
>>> ['admin', 'adam']
```